# How to load xib into two Container Views within one view controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib, container-view

I want to create a single person lap timer xib/class and load it twice onto a single View Controller on my Story Board. Each of the two instances will be used to time and compare two persons lap times on a single ViewController.

I have laid out two Container Views side by side within the Story Board View Controller (LapCounterViewController)

I have also created an xib and class files as a single person lap timer ( LapCounterNibViewContainer)

How do I create two instances of LapCounterNibViewContainer and put it inside each of the Container Views

```
_vc1 = [[LapCounterNibViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LapCounterNibViewController"  bundle:nil];
_vc1.view.frame = self.LapCounterFrame1.frame;
//_vc1.delegate = self;

[_LapCounterFrame1 addChildViewController:_vc1];
[_vc1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview: _vc1.view];
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the storyboard, you can add two container views to the same view controller and connect them both with the same child view controller by right-click dragging and choosing embed. This created the segue like so:

[image: embed segue screenshot]

Click on the segue and give it an identifier. Then, add the `prepareForSegue` method to your parent view controller, and set some properties for the lap timers separately if you want.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"embedSegueToLapTimerOne"]) {
        LapCounterNibViewController * childViewController = (LapCounterNibViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        [childViewController setFoo:bar1];
    }
    if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"embedSegueToLapTimerTwo"]) {
        LapCounterNibViewController * childViewController = (LapCounterNibViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        [childViewController setFoo:bar2];
    }
    }
```